# iOS 7 Icon like Chrome or Youtube icon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icons, ios7

I'm trying to create a iOS 7 icon like Chrome and Youtube new icons. I used base grids to create the iOS 7 icon, but the depth in the bottom and the curve are different.
I was looking for documentation with the right measures to achieve the same effect.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/

There is a section on 'App Icons' a bit down the page